# Unpacking an Optional value

Tags: python, mypy

I have an `Optional[str]` that I know `is not None` and am passing this into a method that requires a `str` argument.

MyPy complains that the types do not match (`Optional[str]` vs `str`). I'm trying to write a method to unpack the wrapped value in optional and would like it to be generic so I don't need to write one for each final datatype.

I can't seem to find what the type of T is so I may do the appropriate cast. Below is the incorrect code:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Optional, cast

T = TypeVar('T')

def unpack_optional(cls, opt: Optional[Generic[T]]) -> T:
    if opt is None:
        raise ValueError("Cannot unpack None into T")
    packed_value = cast(T, opt)
    return packed_value
```

Is it possible to do this in Python?

Answer (score 3):

It's way simpler than what you're trying:

```
T = TypeVar('T')

def unpack_optional(opt: Optional[T]) -> T:
    if opt is None:
        raise ValueError("Optional value is None")
    return opt
```

It looks like you might have been trying to access the concrete type bound to `T` at runtime or something like that, but that's unnecessary. Even the `cast` is unnecessary, because mypy already narrows the type of `opt` after the `None` check.

If you want to `cast` anyway, you can:

```
def unpack_optional(opt: Optional[T]) -> T:
    if opt is None:
        raise ValueError("Optional value is None")
    return cast(T, opt)
```

Comment: Also, this function seems a little pointless. In the context I imagine you would use this, the argument probably should not have been typed as `Optional` in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, it was typed as Optional because None is a valid value for it. mypy was not clever enough to pick up on a different execution path in the case of None and where the Optional value is actually getting used is in a method that only expects a `str`